# How to save the question "Daughter wants to advocate physician-assisted suicide as her life goal. Shall she be professor?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Many apologies for [Daughter wants to advocate physician-assisted suicide as her life goal. Shall she be professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/134238/75817). How do I edit it and make it on-topic? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a legit question about whether/which academic jobs facilitate advocating for social/political change.

For example, advocacy is a terrible fit for most science departments: even departments that don't mind the attention will be vastly more interested in the professor's ability to run a successful research program (i.e., land grants and publish papers). Political science might be an option, but I think most departments focus on how policy decisions are made rather than the policies themselves. I know even less about philosophy/bioethics, but those areas do seem more interested in staking out a position. I think this could probably be fleshed out into a more complete answer with examples, though I don't know enough to do it myself.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure you can, but your question is pretty unclear so maybe you can. It seems you are looking for recommendations about undergraduate programs to prepare your daughter for something. This is likely off topic. You say you think she wants to be a professor, but I am not sure how that relates to the rest of the question. Even if she wants to be a professor, a question about the best career path for becoming a professor is going to lead to opinion based answers. You should take a look at our [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help) and familiarize yourself with our community.